# ModRewrite Ignoring my first rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my htaccess which lies in the public_html/ of my site:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(mailinglist)/.*$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am not sure this works. When I go to http://www.mysite.com/mailinglist that is fine and it does not try to do the last rule above. When I go to http://www.mysite.com/mailinglist/login that works too. http://www.mysite.com/mailinglist/campaigns works as well. When it does not work is when I go to http://www.mysite.com/mailinglist/w/1 it uses the last RewriteRule which is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I make this htaccess completely ignore my /mailinglist directory and anything inside it? In that directory I have a different htaccess which I want that directory to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your mailinglist rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^/?mailinglist - [L,NC]
```

or you can add it as an exception to the index.php rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mailinglist
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```